# Failed to create table: Undefined parameter - ERROR_MESSAGE

Tags: google-bigquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlAkE.png)
I encountered this issue recently. I tried to create a table from the dataset employee_data. But no matter how I tried, I can not create the table anymore. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the CSV file contains jagged row or unreadable characters. Also the schema is auto-detect.

1. Please try giving the schema
2. In the advanced section, click on "Allow Jagged Row" and "Allow Quoted Newlines" and then try loading it again

The error message is generic and does not provide any information as such